# Problem with Career advertisements on SO

Tags: support, jobs, advertising

Not sure if this is the correct forum to post this to, but here goes:

I've been using SO and SF for a few years now and as a developer, it is a must have site for me while I'm working.

The problem is, I work in a "bull pen" environment, and recently a lot of management have been seated near us. As is the case managers^dpeople wonder around, and from time to time they notice the websites that people have open on their screens.

My problem is over the last several months a few managers have noticed SO but specifically the large careers ads posted on the sides of Q/As. They immediately think its a career/ job search website - thinking I'm about to bail, which then requires me to sit down and explain to them what SO really is all about - that is those that are willing to openly comment.

My question, I'd really like to support SO, but is there a away to get the careers advertising turned off, at least for the periods I'm at work? - It's really becoming a hassle, and moving jobs just because of this issue is not really a possibility at this time due various financial constraints etc.

Do other people have experience similar problems at work?

Comment: Ads will be automatically turned off for you when you reach 200 reputation points (except for the bar to the right). That might take the biggest headache away

Comment: I'm not concerned about the other ads, just the ones with the phrases that contain the words "career". I'd still very much like to support the community anyway I can....  but it's good to know that after a certain number of points it might go away.

Comment: In that case I'd just turn them off completely using Adblock. Your situation should excuse you to do so :)

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I think I've found a workaround for the problem - use the careers postings to get a new job ;)

Comment: I guess that's an option, however it is rather difficult for me at this time to make the move.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to disable the ads in one fell swoop, but you can disable individual creatives by hovering over the ad and selecting the thumbs down icon (this is cookie based at the moment, so browser and machine specific).

[image]

Comment: So in theory, if I click the thumbs down on all ads, I won't get any more ads?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ad blocker, you can create a rule to hide the element with the ID `hireme`.

I use adblock plus and the filter rule for that is:

```
stackoverflow.com###hireme
```