# Is it possible to remove or hide the 'Careers' advert

Tags: discussion, advertising

Is it possible to set my profile to not display the 'Careers' advertisement on Stackoverflow?

For the third time today a number of people saw me on SO and saw the ad and asked me if i was planning on leaving my job :).

As it is clearly visible, people assume that i am on a jobs site.

Can i disable it?

Comment: No, unless you use an adblocker. You already have reached the 'reduced ads' privilege, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - There are the like/don't like votes on hover. If the OP clicks the don't like every time, the likelyhood of seeing those will go down.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - The ads don't take having a careers account into account.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: The Careers ad has *nothing* to do with having a careers account.

Comment: @Oded: The likelyhood never goes to 0 though, does it?

Comment: @Oded my mistake, misunderstood the question.

Comment: although the newly posted answer is better so perhaps VTC the other one

Comment: I have 200+ reputation on SO but i can still see the ad.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169033/problem-with-career-advertisements-on-so

Comment: 2013 and still seeing ads on the internet!?

Comment: This isn't a dupe, this is about the side-ads, not the banner.

Comment: Exactly. Its the side-ad with text "Careers 2.0" that i want to disable. None of the referred duplicate thread really provide a solution either.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue yesterday. My boss walked around the corner while I was on StackOverflow looking for an answer to a problem. I turned around to see her face in utter shock. She then asked me if I was looking for a new job. I did my best to explain to her that I was simply looking for an answer, but she still seemed a bit disturbed or unaccepting - as if she wasn't sure if she should believe me or not.

Comment: The solution I found for this was to add a filter to block the `#hireme` element. The adblock plus rule for this is `stackoverflow.com###hireme`.

Answer (score 5):

You can vote on ads with the *thumb up* or *thumb down* while hovering over an ad. If you dislike it, it won't be shown to you again.

[image: Block specific ad]

This works for all ads. That way you can block the carrer ads. But you won't be able to block the career - aehm - "info" below the ads.

Comment: I did try this. When i hover the mouse  over the careers ad (on SO), nothing happens.  I can however vote on the ad above it.

Comment: Exactly. You can "remove" specificly carrer ads, but you won't be able to remove the career openings below the ads.

Comment: What happens if you keep clicking offensive? :)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my ad targeting, but the only ads I _ever_ get are Careers ads, with no ad blocker running.  For science, I just clicked the downvote - repetitive on several different Careers ads, but they all keep coming back.  I saw some conference ad on Serverfault yesterday but I really can't remember the last time I got an ad for anything other than Careers on SO. (except for the occasional teaser question from other SE sites)

Comment: I guess I have a vague memory of seeing some Windows Azure ad in the past weeks, but otherwise reload after reload only gets me Careers ads.

Comment: Yes the problem i am having is with the banner ad on the right hand side. The one that says "Careers 2.0"